# SQL database for text file access?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a set of text files (about 50) that each have the same structure:

```
foo_N.txt:
## area 1
this is area 1's text
## area 2
this is area 2's text
## area 3
this is area 3's text
```

These files reside on a server, and I'd like to access them in the fastest possible way and do some basic parsing without getting too close to the hardware and creating a security vulnerability. What would be an effective way to do this? Would SQL be appropriate here? Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I would write a parser/tool to iterate over the files and then import them into a database. If you write that parser well, then you can write queries to your hearts content. But you would need to follow roughly these steps:

1. Discover structure of the files.
2. Create some database objects to store the file data.
3. Write a tool to both iterate over the file, parse them *and* insert them into the database.
4. Query as much as you want.
5. Profit!

I recommend a language like Python to do the parsing and reading of text files if you don't already have a preference.